# SQL Server Alert - Description (None)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-mail, alerts

For every system Alert defined to send an email, we receive a 2 alerts with the following bodies. How do I stop the message with the empty (None) description?

## Empty Alert

#### SQL Server Alert System: 'Severity 010' occurred on \my-server

> DATE/TIME:    1/30/2013 10:22:59 AM
>
> DESCRIPTION:  (None)
>
> COMMENT:  (None)
>
> JOB RUN:  (None)

## Valid Alert

#### SQL Server Alert System: 'Severity 010' occurred on \my-server

> DATE/TIME:    1/30/2013 10:22:59 AM
>
> DESCRIPTION:  Log was backed up. Database: [mydatabase], creation date(time): 2011/10/03(17:20:11), first LSN: 859915:34267:1, last LSN: 859915:192686:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=DISK: {'\\my-backup-server.domain.local\sqldump\my-server\mydatabase\LOG\my-server_mydatabase_LOG_20130130_114000.trn'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>
> COMMENT:  (None)
>
> JOB RUN:  (None)

Here is our definition for the "Severity 10" Alert.

```
EXECUTE msdb..sp_add_alert @name = N'Severity 010'
  , @message_id = 0
  , @severity = 10
  , @enabled = 1
  , @delay_between_responses = 60
  , @notification_message = NULL
  , @include_event_description_in = 1
  , @database_name = N''
  , @event_description_keyword = N''
  , @job_name = NULL
  , @performance_condition = NULL
  , @wmi_namespace = N''
  , @wmi_query = N''
GO
EXECUTE msdb..sp_add_notification N'Severity 010', N'Project Support', 7
GO
```

Comment: If you set up (or have) an alert for something else, say level 16 errors, does the same behaviour occur? Or is it just this one alert?

Comment: Seems to occur on all alerts. At least those that were setup with a similar script.

Answer (score 1):

By recompiling/committing the Alert, the double emails have stopped. It must have been a bad commit initially.

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting your solution Brandon. It looks pretty specific to your setup, so I think it'd be best to close the post 'Too Localized' but don't take that as a sleight!